# Gridsome & hubspot page tracker integration

Tags: api, vue.js, content-management-system, hubspot, gridsome

I am a beginner developer and I recenty started taking on clients. One asked me to integrate their current website that i created with the hubspot page tracker.

i have checked on their developer page, and it doesnt give specific instructions for gridsome rather SPA's as a whole.

I dont know where to embed the code provided.

https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api-/events/tracking-code

My applicaiton is an SPA and i am using gridsome.

my project can be found at https://github.com/chs242/ezras-nashim

i am so lost. If someone can take the time to help a little i'd be super grateful

regards

Comment: Please read the caption of tag `api`.

Answer (score 1):

To embed the code, add the HubSpot script (replace the `xxxxxxx` with your HubId) in `src/main.js`:

```
export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
  Vue.component('Layout', DefaultLayout)

  head.script.push({
    src: 'https://js.hs-scripts.com/xxxxxxx.js',
    body: true
  })
}
```